# Transactional File System for Delphi?

Tags: delphi, transactions, io

Is there any transactional file system implementation for Delphi that you know of? It should work at least on Windows XP and higher (and therefore not make use of the new TxF features). It should allow to execute multiple file operations (delete, move, copy, rename) as a transaction and also provide recovery.

Thanks!

Comment: What are you protecting against?  Also, are you talking about using a container file, or just doing transacted operations on a "normal" filesystem?  Because you're not going to *really* do the latter if the FS itself doesn't support transactions.  You can fake it in quite a few cases but you'll probably have to write all the supporting framework yourself.  Even with a container, you've still got to deal with the semantics of the underlying FS.

Comment: @afrazier: The latter one: transacted operations on normal file system. For example: if 100 files are copied and the 87th fails, the first 86 already copied files should be deleted.

Comment: How could be transactional file system implemented "for Delphi"? If you have to use it in the operating system then it must be implemented for the operating system. If you only want to use it from an application, use a database - they provide transactional support.

Comment: @gabr: I want to use it from my application and I know that databases offer ACID transactions but that was neither the question nor is it possible in this case. I have to do file operations and I want to get as close to ACID as it is possible. btw: there are .NET and Java implementations that tackle this problem for example: http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2001/11/07/atomic.html Just wanted to ask if there is something available in the Delphi world.

Comment: @Smasher: You really need support from the underlying filesystem then.  You can "fake it" by doing changes with copies of the originals and rename swaps, but that requires your app to be designed to operate in such a way.

Comment: Well, given the fact that I can't get support from the underlying file system (WinXP must be supported) that's exactly what I want - "fake" it to get as close to atomicity as possible. I don't even need atomicity for file writes but only for file operations like copy, move or delete.

Comment: @Smasher: The problem with faking it is "how do you deal with external changes"?  You're in the middle of copying 100 files, and something else deleted #87, how do you react?  If it's not an issue, then just keep an action log in your program and write up the ability to undo changes.  (Of course, caching deletes until "commit.")  If that *is* an issue, then your best shot would be attempting to interact with VSS, but will only work on NTFS filesystems.

Comment: Maybe you should explain what you *really* want to solve...

Comment: "For example: if 100 files are copied and the 87th fails, the first 86 already copied files should be deleted" ... what should I explain more? But from all your reactions I guess that there's nothing available for Delphi...which is kind of an answer as well.

Comment: @Smasher: A copy failing because of a read error or out of space at destination vs. an external source changing the initial conditions are 2 very different failure modes.  With a real transaction, an external event can't delete a file out from under you.  You can get awfully close to real transactions by interacting with VSS or you can fake it badly with an action log and undo system.

Comment: @afrazier: Thanks for your productive input! I will have a look at VSS.

Answer (score 2):

I am afraid your only way around this is to use structured storage.
Actually you have a few options here: the free route or the commercial one.
Free route: use [GPStructuredStorage](http://17slon.com/gp/gp/gpstructuredstorage.htm) to do your processing. When you're happy with the result, just copy over your files.

Commercial route: there are a few component packages(for a fee) which also have native Windows drivers. What happens there is that users "see" the files on their hard drive the way they used to, but you're actually storing them in a compound file.
I believe a few of them even have some kind of "file history" in place so that you can go backwards in time - but I am not sure about that bit.

Andrea

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could use [COM Structured Storage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa378871%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but unfortunately this is not an option in this case. The files I have to work with exist and I cannot change the way they are stored.